# Python LDA gensim "DeprecationWarning: invalid escape sequence"

Tags: r, python-3.x, export-to-csv, gensim, deprecation-warning

I am new to stackoverflow and python so please bear with me.
I am trying to run an Latent Dirichlet Analysis on a text corpora with the gensim package in python using PyCharm editor. I prepared the corpora in R and exported it to a csv file using this R command:

```
write.csv(testdf, "C://...//test.csv", fileEncoding = "utf-8")
```

Which creates the following csv structure (though with much longer and already preprocessed texts):

```
,"datetimestamp","id","origin","text"
1,"1960-01-01","id_1","Newspaper1","Test text one"
2,"1960-01-02","id_2","Newspaper1","Another text"
3,"1960-01-03","id_3","Newspaper1","Yet another text"
4,"1960-01-04","id_4","Newspaper2","Four Five Six"
5,"1960-01-05","id_5","Newspaper2","Alpha Bravo Charly"
6,"1960-01-06","id_6","Newspaper2","Singing Dancing Laughing"
```

I then try the following essential python code (based on the [gensim tutorials](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/tutorial.html)) to perform simple LDA analysis:

```
import gensim
from gensim import corpora, models, similarities, parsing
import pandas as pd
from six import iteritems
import os
import pyLDAvis.gensim

class MyCorpus(object):
     def __iter__(self):
             for row in pd.read_csv('//mpifg.local/dfs/home/lu/Meine Daten/Imagined Futures and Greek State Bonds/Topic Modelling/Python/test.csv', index_col=False, header = 0 ,encoding='utf-8')['text']:
                 # assume there's one document per line, tokens separated by whitespace
                 yield dictionary.doc2bow(row.split())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(row.split() for row in pd.read_csv(
        '//.../test.csv', index_col=False, encoding='utf-8')['text'])
    print(dictionary)
    dictionary.save(
        '//.../greekdict.dict')  # store the dictionary, for future reference

    ## create an mmCorpus
    corpora.MmCorpus.serialize('//.../greekcorpus.mm', MyCorpus())
    corpus = corpora.MmCorpus('//.../greekcorpus.mm')

    dictionary = corpora.Dictionary.load('//.../greekdict.dict')
    corpus = corpora.MmCorpus('//.../greekcorpus.mm')

    # train model
    lda = gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel(corpus=corpus, id2word=dictionary, num_topics=50, iterations=1000)
```

I get the following error codes and the code exits:

> ...\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools-28.8.0-py3.6.egg\pkg_resources_vendor\pyparsing.py:832: DeprecationWarning: invalid escape sequence \d
>
> \...\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools-28.8.0-py3.6.egg\pkg_resources_vendor\pyparsing.py:2736: DeprecationWarning: invalid escape sequence \d
>
> \...\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools-28.8.0-py3.6.egg\pkg_resources_vendor\pyparsing.py:2914: DeprecationWarning: invalid escape sequence \g
>
> \...\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\pyLDAvis_prepare.py:387:
> DeprecationWarning:
> .ix is deprecated. Please use
> .loc for label based indexing or
> .iloc for positional indexing

I cannot find any solution and to be honest neither have any clue where exactly the problem comes from. I spent hours making sure that the encoding of the csv is utf-8 and exported (from R) and imported (in python) correctly.

What am I doing wrong or where else could I look at? Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DeprecationWarining` is exactly that - warning about a feature being *deprecated* which is supposed to prompt the user to use some other functionality instead to maintain the compatibility in the future. So in your case I would just watch for the update of libraries that you use.

Starting with the last warning it look like it is originating from `pandas` and has been logged against `pyLDAvis` [here](https://github.com/bmabey/pyLDAvis/issues/96).

The remaining ones come from `pyparsing` module but it does not seem that you are importing it explicitly. Maybe one of the libraries you use has a dependency and uses some relatively old and deprecated functionality. To eradicate the warning for the start I would check if upgrading does not help. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did not realize the problem was with pyLDAvis and not with gensim. The link solved it for me (or at least I understand the problem now). Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
import warnings   
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")  
pyLDAvis.enable_notebook()
```

Try using this

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).